# Comparing Two Dataframes to See if One Sits Inside the Range of the Other's columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, loops

I have 2 dataframes as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df_test = {
    "col1": [1, 5, 6, 5],
    "col2": [4, 5, 6, 7],
    "col3": [5, 9, 10, 11],
    "col4": [11, 10, 10, 4],
}
df_train = {
    "col1": [3, 6, 7, 4, 4],
    "col2": [5, 10, 5, 5, 5],
    "col3": [6, 8, 9, 10, 6],
    "col4": [11, 10, 8, 12, 6],
}
df_train = pd.DataFrame(data=df_train)
df_test = pd.DataFrame(data=df_test)
```

I have already found the min and max values of df_train and want to see if df_test sits within these values, I want to iterate through each row, continually changing the min and max values as given for each column of the training set. I continually compare each value in the df_test row to see if it fits inside the min and max. If yes, then i will insert True to a list, else I'll write False.

```
# find minMax
df_train_minMax = df_train.agg([min, max])

# identify no of columns and rows in test data
columns = len(df_test.columns)
rows = len(df_test.index)
```

```
df_train_minMax looks like:

     col1  col2  col3  col4
min     3     5     6     6
max     7    10    10    12
```

I have made 2 lists - list receives True or False values per row of df_test. list2 receives the index location of the False values. And then I've made a loop to iterate through df_test, although its becoming very complicated to read. I am certain there is a better and simpler way of doing this.

```
list = []
list2 = []

def inRange(min, max):
    x = 0
    # i = index, j = columns
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(rows), range(columns)):
        if df_test.iloc[i, j] >= min and df_test.iloc[i, j] <= max:
            x = x + 1
        else:
            x = x + 0
            list2.append((i, j))
        # print(x)
    if x == columns:
        list.insert(i, "True")
    else:
        list.insert(i, "False")

# calling function would need the values to continually change per min/max of each column
inRange(5, 10)

print(list) 
print(list2)
```

Expected:

list = [False, True, True, False]
list2 = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3)] or similar

calling function should continually update the min and max values in accordance with the columns in df_train_minMax, which is what I'm struggling to code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace values of each row using `mask` and setting as conditional numbers less or equal and greater or equal than x that is the value in a dataframe you iterate

```py
>>> df_mask = df_test.mask(lambda x: (x>=5) & (x<=10))
>>> df_mask.values.tolist() 
[[1.0, 4.0, nan, 11.0], [nan, nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, nan, nan], [nan, nan, 11.0, 4.0]]
```

At this point pass through each element and if just contains `True` values means that you insert `"True"` because that entire row match for your condition between min and max numbers (5, 10)

```py
>>> min_num, max_num = 5, 10
>>> df_mask = df_test.mask(lambda x: (x>=min_num) & (x<=max_num))
>>> df_mask
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0   1.0   4.0   NaN  11.0
1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3   NaN   NaN  11.0   4.0
>>> df_mask = df_mask.isnull()
>>> df_mask
    col1   col2   col3   col4
0  False  False   True  False
1   True   True   True   True
2   True   True   True   True
3   True   True  False  False
>>> df_mask = df_mask.values.tolist()
>>> df_mask
[[False, False, True, False], [True, True, True, True], [True, True, True, True], [True, True, False, False]]
# ...
>>> list2 = ["True" if (len(set(i)) == 1 and list(set(i))[0] == True) else "False" for i in df_mask]
>>> list2
['False', 'True', 'True', 'False']
```

## EDIT:

added inRange function and modified args

```py
def inRange(min_num, max_num, df):
    # only True values match condition min < x > max 
    # (optional) create colum using list values
    return df.mask(lambda x: (x>=min_num) & (x<=max_num)).isnull()

for col in df_train.tolist():
     min_num = min(col)
     max_num = max(col)
     df1 = inRange(min_num, max_num, df_test)
     print([["True" if (len(set(i)) == 1 and list(set(i))[0] == True) else "False" for i in df1.tolist()])
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. My original challenge was to update min_num, max_num with those shown in df_train_minMax. The original dataframe has over 500 min,max values i want to iterate through. Do I create a dict?

Comment: if you iterate by each column of `df_train_minMax` you will get `([3, 7], [5, 10]. [6, 10], [6, 12])` which diferentiates `tolist` to `[3, 5, 10, 12], [7 ,10,10,12]` then if you call `tolist()` and use `min_num = min(df_train_minMax.tolist()[0]), max_num = max(df_train_minMax.tolist()[0])` that is equivalent to (3, 12), then you can use in `df_test.mask(lambda x: (x>=min_num) & (x<=max_num))` and continue rest of code statements to define `list2`.

Comment: This works great until the final line of code. I get this error:

 "True" if (len(set(i)) == 1 and list(set(i))[0] == True) else "False"
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: pass through values using **for** loop `df_train_minMax.tolist()[i]`, set `min` and `max`, mask row values `df_test.mask(lambda x: (x>=min_num) & (x<=max_num), inplace=True)`, make booleans `df_mask = df_mask.isnull()`, ensure you have a list of lists like `[[False, False, True, False],[] ...]` then this condition should work `"True" if (len(set(i)) == 1 and list(set(i))[0] == True) else "False" for i in df_mask`, maybe it is slightly different when you iterating on `df_train_minMax.tolist()[i]` yo get min and max numbers, you will do this procedure (masking, boolean, tolist) multiple times

Comment: suppose `df_test` or `df_train` (whatever you pass to `inRange(min, max, df)`) use [**mask**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) to replace *loop* statement  and list comprehension to determine conditionally "True"/"False".